# How do know target event in advance using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, jquery-events

I have a form having couple of  `textAreas` and buttons there is event `focusout` handled for all `textAreas`. I am facing the problem as soon as `click` event fire on buttons when user done typing in any of `textareas` and click on save buttons only `focusout` called on `textareas` , however click event on buttons didn't work. Here is my `focusout` on `textareas`:

```
$(document).on("focusout", ".fn-enlargeTextarea", function() {
     // wants to capture cause event of focusout and fire after focusout.
     var optionNumber = ($(this).attr('id').replace('1option','')).trim();
     $('#1option'+optionNumber+'_counter').remove();
     $(this).removeClass('textarea-height01').addClass('textarea-height02');     
});
```

I just came to know in advance that , how do know cause event of `focusout` on textareas so that I can fire target event as soon as `focusout` event consumed.

Here are the buttons inside form:

```
<form id="dataPost">
   <c:forEach items="${forumOptions}" var="option" varStatus="loop">
                          <div class="radio m-b-15">
                              <label class="primary-radio row width03" for="option01-01">
                                  <span class="primary-radio-blue col-xs-1 text-right margin-top-1">
                                   <c:out value="${forumOptions[loop.index]}"></c:out>.</span> 
                                  <span class="col-xs-11">
                                      <textarea name="pollQuestionList[0].pollOptionList[${loop.index}].optionText"  id="1option${loop.index+1}" class="form-control fn-input-text fn-input-options textarea-height02"  ></textarea>
                                  </span>
                              </label>
                          </div>
                          </c:forEach>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-dark-black cus-btn btn-preview" id="poll-save-and-preview">Save &amp; Preview</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark-black cus-btn" id="poll-save"> Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark-black cus-btn" id="poll-close"> Close</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn  btn-warning  btn-font cus-btn-pad lpopup" id="poll-publish"> Post</button>
</form>
```

[image: see here]

Comment: Can u please add code for click on button, or some html

Comment: Given the names of the classes, I assume this resizes the textarea?   It's the age-old problem:  user enters text, they "click" on the button, but the button *moves* **during** the click, so the mouse-up part of the "click" is no longer over the button = no click event.  Click = "mouse down + mouse up within a predetermined length of time".  As the button moved, there's no mouse up, so there's no click.

Comment: @freedomn-m see the edit with images.

Comment: I think the more relevant code would be the definitions of textarea-height01 and textarea-height02.   What if you press tab to focus out of the textarea, and then click the button?

Answer (score 0):

If the textarea is fixed then replace ".fn-enlargeTextarea" class name with "#1option${loop.index+1}" id property value.